# PA- filter query

Tags: power-automate

I am getting an error like this in my get Items Filter query.

> The expression "Year eq'2023' and Month eq'11' and Date gr '13'" is not valid. Creating query failed.

My share point list has columns Year, Month and Date

[image]

Comment: Try `gt` instead of `gr` and make sure there are spaces where spaces need to be.

Comment: That didn’t do the trick. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is date actually day?

Comment: An you add a screenshot of the failed step with as much info as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The internal names of the fields were different. This is the link that helped me sooo much since I dont have access to list settings.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMCk9UnhlJU

Answer (score 0):

If Year, Month, Date/Day are numbers then drop the single quotes in the Filter Query.